# Explain what paintComponent() and drawImage() do and how they do it?

Tags: java, paintcomponent, drawimage

I'm dissecting this tutorial on 2d games and I don't understand exactly what the `paintComponent()` and `drawImage()` methods are doing in this code and why. Could someone please explain?

```
public class Board extends JPanel  {

    private final int B_WIDTH = 350;
    private final int B_HEIGHT = 350;
    private final int INITIAL_X = -40;
    private final int INITIAL_Y = -40;    
    private final int INITIAL_DELAY = 100;
    private final int PERIOD_INTERVAL = 25;

    private Image star;
    private Timer timer;
    private int x, y;

    public Board() {


        initBoard();        
    }

    private void loadImage() {

        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("star.png");
        star = ii.getImage();        
    }

    private void initBoard() {

        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(B_WIDTH, B_HEIGHT));
        setDoubleBuffered(true);

        loadImage();

        x = INITIAL_X;
        y = INITIAL_Y;

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ScheduleTask(), 
                INITIAL_DELAY, PERIOD_INTERVAL);        
    }


    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        drawStar(g);
    }

    private void drawStar(Graphics g) {

        g.drawImage(star, x, y, this);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    }


    private class ScheduleTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            x += 1;
            y += 1;

            if (y > B_HEIGHT) {
                y = INITIAL_Y;
                x = INITIAL_X;
            }

            repaint();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great summary of the repaint operations in AWT and Swing:

[Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#smart)

The specifics on the methods you're asking about are here, but I would start with the higher level article first.

[Graphics.drawImage javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver))

[JComponent.paintComponent javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/awt/Component.html)

Comment: I think your top link is broken.